# Connecting To Database using sqli or PDO in class

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I'm using this class using mysql but realised it's been deprecated. I'm trying to get it to work using PDO or mysqli but I'm not 100% sure how to get it working.

```
class DB {
    private $link;
    private $host, $username, $password, $database;
    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){
        $this->host        = $host;
        $this->username    = $username;
        $this->password    = $password;
        $this->database    = $database;

        $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");

        mysqli_select_db( $this->link,$this->database)
            OR die("There was a problem selecting the database.");

        return true;
    }
    public function query($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
        return $result;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysqli_close($this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }

public function gettingDepartments(){
        $db = new DB("localhost", "root", "", "visitorform");
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_user_dept");
        return $result;
  }


}
```

This is the error I get:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given.
>   mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: You are passing in a variable called `$link` to `mysqli_query()` but not setting it anywhere...

Comment: I'm guessing `$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);` should probably be `$result = mysqli_query($this->link,$query);`

Comment: Nice to see someone realising its depreciated and not completely ignoring that fact.

Comment: @AlexK. it makes a refreshing change for sure on SO

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error message you are not passing in a valid parameter to `mysqli_query()` and nothing at all to `mysqli_error()`.

In your `DB` class `query()` method you are passing a local variable named `$link` to `mysqli_query()` which hasn't yet been set (hence it is telling you it is `null`). Instead, you need to pass in your class variable.

Similarly you need to pass your same class instance variable of `$link` to [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) which you are not doing.

Your updated code for your `DB` class `query()` method should be updated as below:

```
public function query($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
    if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($this->link));
    return $result;
}
```